# Why doesn't asterisk work in Xcode Quick Help markup?

Tags: xcode, formatting, documentation, markup

As [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1) states, you can use `*`,`+` or `-` characters as prefixes for markup keywords. For example, take a look at [`Parameter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Parameter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH28-SW1):

[image]

Now, when I try to use `*`, markup doesn't work:

```
/**
 * Parameter piece: A piece to validate.
 * Parameter matchBlock: Called only if necessary.
 */
init(piece: MSPiece?, matchBlock: MatchBlock) { ... }
```

The above code results in:
[image]

But if we put `+` or `-` instead of `*`,

```
/**
 + Parameter piece: A piece to validate.
 - Parameter matchBlock: Called only if necessary.
 */
init(piece: MSPiece?, matchBlock: MatchBlock) { ... }
```

The documentation will be correct:
  [image]

Why doesn't `*` work? It would be actually cool to use an asterisk because `/** */` comment stats and ends with asterisk and it would be really neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and it's fixed in Xcode 10.0.